# Custom Post type loop with ACF not displaying properly

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I'm having a problem displaying my custom post type in a WP_query loop, under my post thumbnail image I keep seeing signs (">) like I'm not closing the tags properly. Also under that image my first custom field where I show a price is not showing at all, but I know it's there and it works properly if I use

```
highlight_string("<?php\n\$ACF-fields =\n" . var_export(get_fields(), true) . ";\n?>");
```

I see the price value.

This is the loop:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    "post_type" => "piso"
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="pisos-grid-item-wrap <?php $comprar_alquilar ?>"

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', array('width'=>'270') ); ?>">
    </a>

    <h1> <?php echo $precio ?> € </h1>
    <h2> <?php the_title(); ?> </h2>
    <h3> <?php echo $donde ?> </h3>

</div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Also, this is probably worth a new question, but is there an easy way to add a custom field as a class of my main post wrap?

Comment: Check the syntax in the first block of the code you've forgotten to markdown.

Comment: Markdown? You could write it so I can accept it.

Comment: The markdown in the question is already fixed. Now you check the code you've written there.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. It's still not closed properly, you've actually now left the main div open, but it displays the same anyway.

Comment: I didn't change the code, only formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Try and remove `the_post_thumbnail` function from the `img` tag. On its own `the_post_thumbnail` prints out the `img` tag so there seems to be two `img` tag ending in your script.